# Call Recording in Windows mobile 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am trying to develop a call recording application for specific company for their marketing department ,however i know that the microphone is muted for 3rd party applications in Windows Phone 8.1 but i wonder if its gonna be available in windows mobile 10 ? or is there any other way to record calls natively?

Comment: The internal Voice Recorder app can do it... I'm also trying to find out whether it will be possible, either by building a custom app or by locking the feature on a managed device. Anyway I want to force recording all in and outgoing phone calls and don't let the user delete recorded calls (recorded calls has to be synchronized to a server for archive)